# Ember getting killed during install

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, digital-ocean

got a problem:
I have a droplet in digitalocean, and I'm trying to install ember-cli there.
It keeps getting killed for some reason and I can't quite figure it out.
I haven’t found a lot of info on that.

This is how I'm installing -

```
npm install -g ember-cli
```

this is the message I get -

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ember-cli
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ember-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ember-cli/-/ember-cli-0.2.7.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ember-cli/-/ember-cli-0.2.7.tgz
Killed
```

My droplet has 512 RAM and 20GB of space.
could it be because of the low RAM? maybe doing something not right?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check `/var/log/messages`? If it's because of low ram (which I suspect is likely) it should let you know in there

Comment: no messages file there. I've searched for something similar but haven't found one there.
any other ideas?

Comment: There are some comments at Digital Ocean that seems to point out on the low RAM, for example: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/npm-gets-killed-no-matter-what

Comment: Tried increasing my swapfile, didn't work...still getting killed

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the code fetching taking too much time. Try to increase your [`fetch-retry-maxtimeout`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#fetch-retry-maxtimeout) parameter :

in a `.npmrc` file

`fetch-retry-maxtimeout = 120000`

Another hypothesis, look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30572833/2590861

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem :/ and it seems like it's because you don't have enough memory (crazy, I know!). see this link here: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3939

hope it helps,
--imre